# How do I pull in new products and have them be displayed in a carousel in Magento?

Tags: php, javascript, magento, jcarousellite

I'm somewhat of a noob with Magento. I was wondering if there was a way to display new products on the home page by using jcarouselLite? I have static content in there now for a placer. Is there a way to pull in products that are newly listed and have it be displayed in the carousel? If so, how would I go about doing that? I unfortunately don't have a link to show as of right now. I appreciate any help/advice.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but there are some themes available that have this built in. If you haven't already themed the site, might be a simpler way than writing something.

Comment: it's already themed. Know of any other way?

Answer (score 0):

For any product, check if current date matches with new from date or new to date for that product then that product will be considered as a new product.

Alternately you can create a category and associate the products to be shown as new with this category and then show the product associated with that category